# Sync Plugin Timeout issue

Tags: .net, plugins, dynamics-crm

I'm tasked with importing over 100 line items from an Excel sheet. Due to real-time error handling requirements, asynchronous processing and bulk operations aren't viable options. The process involves reading the Excel sheet and creating or updating line items accordingly.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this challenge effectively would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would still go for the **asynchronous** (background) option as it can be designed as a relatively straight forward solution, e.g. by using a Power Automate flow and some code.

By "real-time error handling requirements" you probably mean that the user should be informed about the progress of the import operation and that error messages can be presented to him. This is still possible in asynchronous scenarios, e.g. by using toast messages. (See [Send in-app notifications within model-driven apps | MS Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/send-in-app-notifications?tabs=clientapi).)

When you really want to go **synchronous** (i.e. in a foreground process) an option is designing a custom HTML web resource offering a UI surface (dialog, pane or page a.o.) where the user can upload his file. Of course this would also involve Javascript code and CSS.